# Shortcuts for WebSphere Admin Console pages?

Tags: websphere, admin, shortcut, websphere-7, websphere-6.1

I'm working with IBM's WebSphere Application Server 6.1 and 7, and the more I work with it, the more I find myself spending a lot of time drilling down to components.  I understand that with WebSphere 7, they introduced tasks that allow high level pages to be bookmarked; but what about certain components that are deeply buried?

A good example of this would be for Application Server JVM properties.  To view or change these, the following links/drop-downs must be navigated (this is for WAS 7):

*Servers > Server Types > WebSphere Application Servers > [server name] > Java and Process Management > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine*

Drilling can become quite tedious.  Is anyone aware of the capability for shortcuts, or bookmarks to these component pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're frequently making the same changes to your servers, I would suggest scripting those updates with the `wsadmin` tool that ships with WAS. It might take a little time to learn and get the scripts just right but once they're setup, common configuration tasks take no brain power and very little time.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.base.doc%2Finfo%2Faes%2Fae%2Ftxml_scriptingep.html

Comment: Thanks Nick!  I'm familiar with `wsadmin`, and the convenience it provides.  Maybe I'll spend some time on creating these scripts, instead of wishing for bookmarks.  Typing is quicker than clicking after all.